# Vici.CoolStorage: filter with ManyToOne and ManyToMany relation

Tags: c#, orm, coolstorage, vici

I got an exception in Vici.CoolStorage 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'QueryExpression' when using the following filter on the .List() method of my Event class:

```
Event.List("has(Resource where has(Teams where TeamID = @TeamID))", 
                "@TeamID", teamID);
```

-> Event - Resource = ManyToOne relation (Resource property)

-> Resource - Team = ManyToMany relation, plural=true (CSList Teams property)

I want to retrieve all Events with a Resource that belongs to the specified Team (teamID). Is this possible in the Vici.CoolStorage filter syntax?

ps. teamID = Guid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The has() function should only be used with *ToMany relations. I think you mean this:

I suppose you want to select all records that have a related resource beloning to a specific team?

This could be what you're looking for:

```
Event.List("has(Resource.Teams where TeamID = @TeamID))", 
            "@TeamID", teamID);
```